# Faceted filters in Mongo DB with for products with multiple options

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, faceted-search

we are trying to create call to MangoDB to receive all possible filters for products.

I will try to create example of our products

First product is Adidas Shoes which have two options to select - colour and size. But for different colours you have different sizes.

```
{
    id: 1
    name: "Adidas Shoes",
        filters: [
        [
            {
                code: "brand",
                value: "Adidas"
            },
            {
                code: "colour",
                value: "white"
            },
            {
                code: "size",
                value: 41
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                code: "brand",
                value: "Adidas"
            },
            {
                code: "colour",
                value: "white"
            },
            {
                code: "size",
                value: 42
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                code: "brand",
                value: "Adidas"
            },
            {
                code: "colour",
                value: "white"
            },
            {
                code: "size",
                value: 43
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                code: "brand",
                value: "Adidas"
            },
            {
                code: "colour",
                value: "blue"
            },
            {
                code: "size",
                value: 41
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                code: "brand",
                value: "Adidas"
            },
            {
                code: "colour",
                value: "blue"
            },
            {
                code: "size",
                value: 44
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Second product is Nike Shoes.

```
{
    id: 2
    name: "Nike Shoes",
        filters: [
    [
        {
            code: "brand",
            value: "Nike",
        },
        {
            code: "colour",
            value: "white",
        },
        {
            code: "size",
            value: 41,
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            code: "brand",
            value: "Nike",
        },
        {
            code: "colour",
            value: "white",
        },
        {
            code: "size",
            value: 42,
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            code: "brand",
            value: "Nike",
        },
        {
            code: "colour",
            value: "green",
        },
        {
            code: "size",
            value: 41,
        }
    ]
]
}
```

And Reebook shoes

```
{
    id: 3
    name: "Reebook Shoes",
    filters: [
    [
        {
            code: "brand",
            value: "Reebook",
        },
        {
            code: "colour",
            value: "black",
        },
        {
            code: "size",
            value: 41,
        }
    ]
    ]
}
```

as you can see option size is dependent on colour and colour is dependent on size.

How we can create MongoDb.aggregate to have all possible filters?

**Brand:** Adidas (1), Nike (1), Reebook (1)

**Size:** 41 (3), 42 (2), 43 (1), 44 (1)

**Colour:** White (2), Blue (1), Green (1), Black (1)

And call should be independent on how many and which filters we have (products with one option, products with more options and different filters). Can you explain how to use $group, $unwind in this situation? And how we can improve it later with $facet?

Thanks a lot!!!

**EDIT 02/10/2017**

**Sample response**

```
facets: [
    {
        code: "brand",
        values: [
            {
                name: "Adidas",
                count: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Nike",
                count: 1
            },
            {   
                name: "Reebook",
                count: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        code: "size",
        values: [
            {
                name: 41,
                count: 3
            },
            {
                name: 42,
                count: 2
            },
            {   
                name: 43,
                count: 1
            },
            {   
                name: 44,
                count: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        code: "colour",
        values: [
            {
                name: "White",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "Blue",
                count: 1
            },
            {   
                name: "Green",
                count: 1
            },
            {   
                name: "Black",
                count: 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

or

```
facets: {
    "brand": {
        "Adidas": 1,
        "Nike":1,
        "Reebook":1
    },
    "size": {
        "41": 3,
        "42":2,
        "43":1,
        "44":1
    },
    "colour": {
        "White": 2,
        "Blue":1,
        "Green":1,
        "Black":1
    }
}
```

This is our first stage. Next step will be how to search possible filters when I have selected Size: 41 and Colour: White.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show a sample response you want to get? I'm trying to realize how the dependency between color and size will affect the response and how it should look.

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich 
I added sample response to original

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an aggregation that might work for you.

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 {$unwind: '$filters'},
 {$unwind: '$filters'},
 {
  $group: {
   _id: {code: '$filters.code', value: '$filters.value'},
   products: {$addToSet: '$_id'}
  }
 },
 {
  $project: {
   'filter.value': '$_id.value',
   'filter.count': {$size: '$products'}
  }
 },
 {
  $group: {
   _id: '$_id.code',
   filters: {$push: '$filter'}
  }
 }
]);
```

The data you need comes in a [slightly different format](http://jsbin.com/yufitowoma/1/edit?js) because there's no easy way to convert array of grouped values to object properties.

If some filters are already selected you need another $match stage after the first $unwind.
It also supports multi selects. Say I want white/black shoes made by Reebook/Adidas.

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 {$unwind: '$filters'},
 {
  $match: {
   $and: [
    //Add objects here fo everything that is selected already
    {'filters': {$elemMatch: {code: 'colour', value: {$in: ['black', 'white']}}}},
    {'filters': {$elemMatch: {code: 'brand', value: {$in: ['Adidas', 'Reebook']}}}}
   ]
  }
 },
 {$unwind: '$filters'},
 {
  $group: {
   _id: {code: '$filters.code', value: '$filters.value'},
   products: {$addToSet: '$_id'}
  }
 },
 {
  $project: {
   'filter.value': '$_id.value',
   'filter.count': {$size: '$products'}
  }
 },
 {
  $group: {
   _id: '$_id.code',
   filters: {$push: '$filter'}
  }
 }
]);
```

The last thing is the dependent behavior like this:
Select Nike => Size and Color are filtered by brand but you are still able to select all brands.
Select Nike + 42 Size => You can select only brands having size 42, colors and brands for which there are shoes of 42 size. 
And so on.

You can leverage $facet for it. In fact when the idea is next.
If we're calculating brands - we should filter records by what's selected in size and color dropdowns.
If we're calculating size - applying color and brand. Same logic for color.

Here is the code that worked in mongo shell:

```js
//This hash is going to by dynamic
//Add and remove properties, change $in arrays
//Depending on what user does
var conditionsForUserSelect = {
 'colour': {'filters': {$elemMatch: {code: 'colour', value: {$in: ['green']}}}},
 'brand': {'filters': {$elemMatch: {code: 'brand', value: {$in: ['Nike']}}}},
 'size': {'filters': {$elemMatch: {code: 'size', value: {$in: [41]}}}}
};

var getFacetStage = function (code) {
 //Empty object, accept all filters if nothing is selected
 var matchStageCondition = {};

 var selectedFilters = Object.keys(conditionsForUserSelect);
 if (selectedFilters && selectedFilters.length) {
  //Take all queries EXCEPT for the passed
  //E.g. if we are counting brand filters then we should apply color and size.
  //Because for example if no size/colour selected we should
  //allow all brands even if Reebok is selected
  var conditionsToApply = selectedFilters
   .filter(function (key) {
    return key !== code
   })
   .map(function (key) {
    return conditionsForUserSelect[key]
   });

  if (conditionsToApply && conditionsToApply.length) {
   matchStageCondition = {
    $and: conditionsToApply
   };
  }
 }

 return [
  {$unwind: '$filters'},
  {
   $match: matchStageCondition
  },
  {$unwind: '$filters'},
  {
   $group: {
    _id: {code: '$filters.code', value: '$filters.value'},
    products: {$addToSet: '$_id'}
   }
  },
  {
   $project: {
    'filter.value': '$_id.value',
    'filter.count': {$size: '$products'}
   }
  },
  {
   $group: {
    _id: '$_id.code',
    filters: {$push: '$filter'}
   }
  },
  {
   $match: {_id: code}
  }
 ];
};


db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 {
  $facet: {
   colour: getFacetStage('colour'),
   size: getFacetStage('size'),
   brand: getFacetStage('brand')
  }
 }
]);
```

Comment: As you can see in your results for brand Adidas - there are 5 products what is not true - there is just one product (with 5 options). And also **if you unwind filters twice you lost connection between dependent options** colour and size.

Comment: @Rastislav I updated the queries.
Firs query is getting all possible filters so I think it's ok to unwind twice.
The second one filters ($match) records after the first unwind so the connection between size and color is taken into account.

Comment: @Anthonio
Thank you! It looks great! One small think - there should be possibility to select more values in one filter. For example when you select Adidas there should be possibility to multiselect other brands. Do you understand?

Comment: @Rastislav here you go. Updated again.

Comment: We are close :) I will try to write how it should work. When you have selected color white you should commute other filters like this: You should show all brands which products contains color white, you should show all sizes which products contains color white and you should show all colors (not just white). Then you select size 41 - so you have selected size 41 and color white. You should show all brands which products contains color white AND size 41, you should show all sizes which products contains just color white and you should show all colors which products contains size 41

Comment: thanks :) It is monster :) And do you also know how to use $facet in Mongo 3.4? It would be great also for other users to show how it can be done with new Mongo features as other option :) Thanks

Comment: @Rastislav I used the $facet. :) Check out the last code listing.

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich Thank you so much for your $64000 answer. It helped alot.