# Smart filter with sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, filter, sphinx

How to build correct filter for intenet shop.

For example:
We have mobile phone with name (IPhone, Xiaomi, etc) and parameters (memory,battery capacity).

Question:
I have 5 memory options (1gb,2gb,3gb,4gb,5gb). When i select any of memory option other filters must rebuild with new count, but memory filter must not change. If i use sphinx facet as 
`select * from phones where memory='1gb' facet memory facet name`
i see result where memory only with 1gb with count, this is not good because i must can select phone with 1gb and 2 gb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas sphinx can't direclty do that, the `FACET` function isnt that smart.

Just have to concoct the group by query 'manually'.

```
select * from phones where match('keyword') and memory='1gb';
select memory,count(*) from phones where match('keyword') group by memory;
select name,count(*) from phones where match('keyword') and memory='1gb' group by name;
```

... ie just *omit* the memory filter from the memory group by explicitly. Thats all `FACET` is doing really, automatically creating these extra GROUP BY queries.

Comment: See also https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/issues/248 which expands a bit on this

Comment: Thank you for replay. I found this implementation by mongo db https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141116/faceted-filters-in-mongo-db-with-for-products-with-multiple-options

Comment: Far as can see that does exactly the same thing - just with code, uses a 'filter' in the mapping stage, so that the particular filter does not apply for the particular group by. (like in your example, the memory filter *isn't* added to the memory group by. )